# Count numbers in child categories

Tags: php, mysql

There are two tables.

```
mdl_course_categories:
+----+---------------+----------+
| id | name          |  parent  |
+----+---------------+----------+
| 1  | Some category |  0       |
| 2  | Some category |  1       |
...

mdl_course:
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | category     | name        |
+----+--------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1            | Course name |
...
```

`mdl_course.category` is related to `mdl_course_categories.id`.

So if we have some category with 1 course in it and in this category subcategory with 2 courses, category must have 3 courses and so on.
E.g.:

```
category1 (2 courses there)
 - subcategory1 (8 courses there)
    - subsubcategory (1 course there)
 - subcategory2 (4 courses there)
```

Needed to output:

```
category1 (15=2+8+1+4)
 - subcategory1 (9=8+1)
    - subsubcategory (1)
 - subcategory2 (4)
```

This is my MySQL code:

```
SELECT category.name AS name,

COUNT(mdl_course.category) + (

    SELECT COUNT(mdl_course.category) FROM mdl_course_categories AS subcategory
    LEFT JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_course.category = subcategory.id
    WHERE category.id = subcategory.parent
) AS count

FROM mdl_course_categories AS category
LEFT JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_course.category = category.id
GROUP BY category.id ORDER BY name ASC
```

but it counts only one child level down, not recursively.
Can you please help with more universal code maybe php+mysql?
The goal is to list categories with number of courses in each as sum of courses 
in all subcategories.

Comment: You can easily adopt that code to your current needs (look comment's response to Adriano San Martin): http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/08/php-adjacency-list-hierarchy-tree-traversal.html

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. With your current data you will need to run multiple queries which will be very inefficient. Fastest way to do this (but very slow for updates) is to redesign your database to use the nested set model. If you only have a very limited number of levels it would be possible to code a query that does joins to cope with the max number of levels that can exist, but this would be very inflexible.

Comment: @bad_boy, thank you, I saw it earlier but didn't attach importance to. I tried again and it worked.